# Can you pass a list of strings to AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a program to send a string I got from a GET request to an event in AWS Lambda. I want to store a list of strings from the GET request and then read them in Discord. I am using python.

I have my code working, but I can only do one string at a time. I append the data to a list every time to GET request is called, but testing in Lambda and my AWS Api Gateway instance, I can't seem to get anything back when I send it as a list of strings. I get a 400 Gateway error. Is there a way to do this?

For instance I can send the request to my gateway API https:///mygatewayapi/myFunction?addDessert=cake but cannot do https:///mygatewayapi/myFunction?addDessert=cake&pie. It will either only return cake or will error out. I have tried putting it in double and single quotes, separating the parameters with commas and the ampersand. None of them work.

Comment: You should be able to do that with no issues. Please share more specific details so people can help you.

Comment: For instance I can send the request to my gateway API https:///mygatewayapi/myFunction?addDessert=cake but cannot do https:///mygatewayapi/myFunction?addDessert=cake&pie. It will either only return cake or will error out.

Comment: Please add these details to the body of your question so that nobody misses any crucial details.

Comment: The links you shared are not reproducible - I can't see what's in them, hence can't help...

Comment: Those are my public api gateway links. They are public accessible and I don't want to expose them, hence I replaced them with dummy text. I just want to know if it is possible to pass a list of strings to an AWS event.

Comment: Short answer is yes, definitely, why not; but can't help with the specifics really, since I don't know them.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and remove irrelevant details; keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array to your lambda function like this:

```
{
  "my_array": ["Ford",  "BMW",  "Fiat"]
}
```

Get it on your lambda function like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    // ... 
    let my_array = event['my_array'];
    console.log(my_array[0]);
    // ... 
};
```